# XML Parsing Fatal Error at Line -1, Column -1: Premature end of file when trying to update item quantity in Amazon SP-API

Tags: xml, amazon-selling-partner-api

For the past few weeks I have been trying to update the quantity of a given SKU in amazon through SP API but it seems that I can't get the XML right for it.

This is the error that I am getting:

```
{
    'AmazonEnvelope' => {
        'Header' => {
            'MerchantIdentifier' => 'XXXXXXX',
            'DocumentVersion' => '1.02'
        },
        'MessageType' => 'ProcessingReport',
        'Message' => {
            'MessageID' => 1,
            'ProcessingReport' => {
                'ProcessingSummary' => {
                    'MessagesSuccessful' => 0,
                    'MessagesWithWarning' => 0,
                    'MessagesProcessed' => 0,
                    'MessagesWithError' => 1
                },
                'Result' => {
                    'MessageID' => 0,
                    'ResultMessageCode' => 5001,
                    'ResultDescription' => 'XML Parsing Fatal Error at Line -1, Column -1: Premature end of file. Premature end of file.',
                    'ResultCode' => 'Error'
                },
                'StatusCode' => 'Complete',
                'DocumentTransactionID' => '50206019467'
            }
        }
    },
    '?xml' => ''
}
```

I am using this client https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-sp-api to make requests to Amazon.
This is the XML that I am sending:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
        <Header>
            <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
            <MerchantIdentifier>xxxxxx</MerchantIdentifier>
        </Header>
        <MessageType>Inventory</MessageType>
        <Message>
            <MessageID>1</MessageID>
            <Inventory>
                <SKU>13725</SKU>
                <Quantity>12</Quantity>
            </Inventory>
        </Message>
    </AmazonEnvelope>
```

Comment: did you managed to solve it ?

Comment: no, are you having the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the xsd template that you are supposed to be using? [https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/Inventory.*TTH*.xsd](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/Inventory._TTH_.xsd)

Perhaps you are missing a required field.